# Will Sumatra interfere with git?

Tags: hpc

As far as I understand, [Sumatra](http://neuralensemble.org/sumatra/) does some sort of versioning of simulation scripts and output files. If I start to use Sumatra inside a git working directory, can Sumatra end up interfering with git or vice versa?

Comment: It's not supposed to. From attending a presentation by its author, the impression I got was that Sumatra will record things like output files that wouldn't necessarily be version-controlled by Git (unless you specifically wanted to archive them for some reason).

Comment: I think I will set up a test repository and start messing around with Sumatra in it to see what happens.